# JavaScript 2d array returns wrong data

Tags: javascript, impactjs

I have a 2d array that represents the collision and foreground layers of my game map. I'm trying to get the proper tile based on the player's position to read the tile's number. However when I call the particular tile from the array, it either returns the wrong number or says `Cannot read property 'index here' of undefined`. I have verified by looking at the  array that the indices from the players position should return a non-zero value, however they return a zero or the undefined message. Here is the code I'm using to find the tile position:

```
if (layers[i]["name"] === "collision") {
                var colLayer = layers[i];
                var tileWidth = colLayer["tilesize"];

                x /= tileWidth;
                y /= tileWidth;

                var dataArr = colLayer["data"];

                console.log("X " + dataArr.length + " Y " + dataArr[0].length)

                try {
                    console.log(Math.floor(x) + " " + Math.floor(y+1) + " Block num is " + dataArr[Math.floor(y)][Math.floor(x)]);
                    if (dataArr[Math.floor(x)][Math.floor(y)])
                        return true;
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }
```

And here is the data array for reference:

```
"data": [
                [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,12,12,12,12,12,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,24,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],
                [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
            ]
```

Comment: You should add `console.dir(dataArr)` also, to make sure that you're really dealing with the object you think you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this a long time ago. We're so used to `(X, Y)` coordinates, but in array form it's actually like `(Y, X)`.

So `dataArr[Math.floor(x)][Math.floor(y)]` should be `dataArr[Math.floor(y)][Math.floor(x)]`.

Try that and see if it works.

Comment: That was is. And I was doing this before but I forgot I needed to add 1 to y to compensate for the player's height. Thanks.